# How to make a template function in test.h use a static method inside test.cpp

Tags: c++, templates, static

Currently the template functions are inside the .cpp file, however these templates need to be defined in the header. However, when I move them in to the header, the templates have no access to the static methods inside the .cpp file. What changes do I need for this to work?

This is just a utility header and cpp, nothing to do with classes.

Comment: "... these templates need to be defined in the header." Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "static methods"?

Comment: They need to be defined in the header because we comply to MISRA rules. static methods as in static void method_name() { } not within a class and to be used only by that file

Answer (score 2):

I would just go ahead and put declarations of all needed functions in a header file (and remove the `static` from their definitions).  If you put them in `namespace FunctionName_impl_detail` or something like that, you're safe from name collisions.  If you put comments near the declarations discouraging using them directly, you probably don't need to "hide" or "protect" them.  But if you want to mostly prevent other code from using them, you can make them `private`, `static` members of some class which `friend`s the template functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the static method in the header.

Template classes have to be defined entirely in the header file because the compiler basically creates a new class for each template instantiation, so it has to have access to the full method implementation at compilation time.

Comment: Then won't every file that includes that header also include a  definition of that static method?

Comment: Only if it is declared public.

Comment: The method is only used by the templated function. The header and cpp have nothing to do with classes. There is no public or private...